# Correct install for RVM and Chef

Tags: rvm, chef-infra

I installed `rvm` for multi-user on my `server`.

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable 
sudo usermod -a -G
rvm ubuntu rvm install 2.1.1 
rvm --default use 2.1.1
```

I also installed `Chef`

```
curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | sudo bash
```

But when i run "gem install chef" under `ubuntu` i get

```
 You don't have write permissions into the /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1 directory
```

Obviously i can just change the `permissions` but I'm assuming this isn't how i should set this up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The omnibus installer, aka:

```
curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | sudo bash
```

Installs Chef **for you**. You don't need to install Chef. You can run chef as `chef-client` or `chef-solo`.

Chef get's installed into `/opt/chef` and it packages it's own Ruby, etc.

---

With respect to your RVM issues:

- Have you added the required lines to your `.bashrc`?
- Are you actually executing a login shell (`-l`)?
- Why are you trying to install chef into rvm?